# scrollTop ++ loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am writing a little web app in JavaScript and I am using **TUIO** object to perform a scroll of a **sortable** list in JQuery.

My actions are within an `else if` statement since the prior ones have been defined for other objects that perform other actions. The current action is working, but only does it once, as if I had to click on a button many times to perform the action again. What I am trying to to is to make the `scrollTop` action to loop until it reaches the bottom/top of the content instead of just performing the action once.

Here is what I have:

```
else if (objectId == 6 && rotation) {

            if (rotation > 20 && rotation < 95) {

                console.log ("Scroll Down Action");                 
                $('#sortable').animate({scrollTop: '+=5px'}, 10);

            }
            else if (rotation > 273 && rotation < 340) {

                console.log ("Scroll Up Action");                   
                $('#sortable').animate({scrollTop: '-5px'}, 10);
            };
```

Just as an extra set of informaiton, I am using [Fajran's TUIO JS library](https://github.com/fajran/npTuioClient).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just `scrollTop` to the top and bottom of the document other than having it increment or decrement by 5 pixels each time?

Comment: There is a long list of images that I want the user to look at at their own pace. If it goes all the way to the bottom, the user will not have the chance to stop in a particular part of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a friend just sent me the answer.

First set up a global function that performs the `.animate` scroll and detects the `scrollTop` of the div:

```
var scroller = function(){

var scrolly = $('#sortable').scrollTop();
    if (rotation > 20 && rotation < 95) {
            console.log ("Spinnin Up");                                    
            $('#sortable').animate({scrollTop: scrolly + 10}, 1, scroller)

    }
    else if (rotation > 273 && rotation < 340) {
            console.log ("Spinning Down");
            $('#sortable').animate({scrollTop: scrolly - 10}, 1, scroller)
    };
};
```

After this, call the function within the `if` statement

```
... 

else if (objectId == 6 && rotation) {
          scroller();
});
```

Furthermore, for some reason, if I dont use .animate, the function does not work. But anyways, it works now.